# Django - How to deserialize json into a nested object

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization

I have the following problem. I need to create a complex object using data POSTed in json. In the models.py file, I have the main object called "Company":

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descr = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then I have "Building":

```
class Building(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    location = models.TextField()
    company= models.ForeignKey("Company", related_name="buildings", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And so on with other few classes (i.e. "Floor", "Area", "Room").

The json I get from the POST request is:

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "buildings": [{
        "id": 3,
        "floors": [{
            "id": 1,
            "floor": -1,
            "descr": "underground",
            "building": 3
        }],
        "areas": [{
            "id": 1,
            "rooms": [{
                "id": 1,
                "floor": 1,
                "area": 1,
                "descr": "First Room"
            }],
            "descr": "Dev area",
            "building": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Sede",
                "city": "Rome",
                "location": "mylocation",
                "company": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Test",
                    "descr": "Test"
                }
            }
        }],
        "name": "Sede",
        "city": "Rome",
        "location": "mylocation",
        "company": 1
    }],
    "name": "Test",
    "descr": "Test"
}
```

When I try to create a "Company" object from the json I get, it only creates the following:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "buildings": [],
    "name": "Test",
    "descr": "Test"
}
```

and not the full structure.

My serializers are the following:

```
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    floors= FloorSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    areas = AreaSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    buildings= BuildingSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

How can I resolve this?

P.S. I know the json is a bit redundant!

Answer (score 0):

99% of the times when you don't get the nested data is because you're sending a JSON payload with a form content type.

Make it explicit in your client that you're sending JSON by setting the Content-Type header to `application/json` and that should fix the content issue.

Comment: I already specified the `application/json` format in the *Content-Type* header.

Answer (score 0):

You specify buildings as a read-only field: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields

Try removing that parameter in the serializer:

```
class BuildingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    floors= FloorSerializer(many=True)
    aree = AreaSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Building
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    buildings= BuildingSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

Comment: If i remove `read_only=True` it says that the json is not valid (serializer method __is_valid()__ fails).

Comment: Oh, that's the redundancy issue. You should get rid of that. In general, you only avoid posting structures nested more than 2 level.

Comment: I'm trying with this: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: Have you tried removing the recursive data structure? I think you'll need that. Otherwise just imagine what should Django do if the building object nested in areas' buildings field have the same pk but different field values? by the way if `is_valid()` fails, it should return an error message. What does it say?